# Is there a way to merge 2 dataframes with a labda function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

The first one includes a list of personal and name column looks following:

*Surname, Name*

The second one includes more, but the column with the name looks other:

*Name Surname* (and sometimes something else like a number or a letter)

I should merge the dataframes with. Do I have just iterate each row and create a new dataframe or is there something else?

Example of dataframes:

```
list1 = [
  {
    'Name': 'Mann, Max', 
    'Position': 'Support'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Fischer, John',
    'Position': 'Student'
  }
]

list2 = [
  {
    'Name': 'John 12 Fischer',
   //further
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Max Mann E',
   //further
]
```

Comment: Alway aviod iterating each row in a dataframe. Have you tried `pd.join` or `pd.merge`?

Comment: Why would you want to create a new dataframe for every row in the original frames? If you want to merge the information from 2 dataframes, then shouldn't be the result one dataframe? As loopy suggested: join or merge could be good points to start, but to help you better, it would be good to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: I'm trying, but I don't see any way.

If I'll use it, I won't have any point that could join/merge data. The single point where i can bind dataframes is the name. But names have not the same format.

Comment: Without knowing what you call *merging*, I cannot help. Do you just want to concatenate columns of the second after the ones from the first? (it would assume that index of rows in both dataframe are the same)

Comment: That is the problem. Indexes aren't same. Format of names isn't same. I want to get one dataframe from both.

Comment: I thought I could give a function in merge that would compare indexes by another way

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. You can:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                   

In [2]:  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,54], 'b':[1,2,3,4]})                                                                                                  

In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7,8,0,50], 'd':[31,12,13,12]})                                                                                               

In [4]: df1.append(df2)                                                                                                                                       
Out[4]: 
      a    b     c     d
0   1.0  1.0   NaN   NaN
1   2.0  2.0   NaN   NaN
2   3.0  3.0   NaN   NaN
3  54.0  4.0   NaN   NaN
0   NaN  NaN   7.0  31.0
1   NaN  NaN   8.0  12.0
2   NaN  NaN   0.0  13.0
3   NaN  NaN  50.0  12.0
```

This I think is the most easiest, but you can also do SQL type merging with inner and outer joins, just like an SQL table. More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: There is not point where I can write ´left_on´ and ´right_on´

Comment: So if i am understanding correctly, you want the stuff in list2 to appear in list1? i am also reading your comments from the question, you do not have to worry about not having common column names, as in my example pandas conveniently fills it up with NaNs

Comment: Yes. By this way I'll get double data. *Fischer, John* and *John Fischer* is the same person which name is written in a different format. Thank you for your answer. I think I should think about "how to update" and not "how to merge".

Comment: I would go about by splitting the name first into `firstname`,  `lastname` and then go about merging with inner joins, which somehow works like an intersection while joining. More info on the link above, good luck!

Comment: I've iterated it where i did split and used a regular expression. I didn't find a more beautifully way. At first I thought that I could do merging with an own compare function. The iterating took about 3 minutes. Now I can work on data further. Thank you!